# VueJS cannot read property 'name' of undefined causing UI error

Tags: vue.js, conditional-statements

I have wrapped the piece of code that should be displayed conditionally in a template tag but it keeps trying to read the name property even when it's not present.

Trying to find a way to display the name field on the template only when present.

```
<template v-if='api && api.info.contact.name'>
    <strong>Developer:</strong> {{api.info.contact.name || api._meta.github_username }}<br>
</template>
```

even tried to display a username by adding an OR statement but all fails.

help?

Comment: You're not checking wether api._meta.github_username exists in your conditional rendering. So if any of those attributes is undefined, the rendering will fail.

Comment: github_username is always there. it's 'name' that causes the error.  Is that still a problem?

Comment: do you use js or ts?

Comment: @Maxim javascript

Comment: Any time you try to use a property of something that might be undefined you could have this problem. In this case, it appears that *sometimes* `api.info.contact` is undefined. Try this instead: `v-if='api && api.info.contact'`. And you might want to check `api.info` as well if it could ever be undefined.

Comment: Or, i guess to be super safe, `v-if='api && api.info && api.info.contact && api._meta'`.

Comment: @MarcoAlvarado you could create a Proxy object which will convert your object to save object. Save object will return {} when propertry is undefined.

Comment: @Maxim could you show me how you would do that, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<template v-if='api && api.info.hasOwnProperty("name")'>
    <strong>Developer:</strong> {{api.info.contact.name || api._meta.github_username }}<br>
</template>
```

hasOwnProperty ended up working finally

Answer (score 0):

You could create Proxy which will return empty object {} when property is undefined. Something like Elvis opertor in TypeScript.

```
function safe(obj) {
  return new Proxy(obj, {
    get: function(target, name) {
      const result = target[name];
      if (!!result) {
        return (result instanceof Object)? safe(result) : result;
      }
      return safe({});
    }
  });
}
```

Usage example:

```
const jane = {
  name: 'Jane',
  age: 35
};

const john = {
  name: 'John',
  address: {
    street: '7th Avenue',
    city: 'Ecmaville',
    zipCode: '23233'
  },
  sister: jane,
  age: 28
};
var sjohn = safe(john);                    
console.log(sjohn.name);                  // --> "John"
console.log(sjohn.address.street);        // --> "7th Avenue"
console.log(sjohn.sister.name);           // --> "Jane"
console.log(sjohn.sister.address);        // --> {}
console.log(sjohn.sister.address.street); // --> {}
```